# Firebase function TypeError .once is not a function and onCreate not working

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I was trying to deploy a function to Firebase to send notifications to all admin accounts when a new user signs up to the app, this is my current code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.newDoctorNotification = functions.database.ref("/doctors/{pushId}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const newDoctorID = context.params.pushId;
      const notificationContent = {
        notification: {
          title: "New Doctor",
          body: "A new doctor just signed up! uid: " + newDoctorID,
          icon: "default",
          sound: "default",
        },
      };

      const adminTokensRef = functions.database.ref("device_tokens/admin");
      const tokens = [];

      adminTokensRef.once("value", (querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((adminToken) => {
              tokens.push(adminToken.val());
            });
          });

      if (tokens.length > 0) {
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, notificationContent)
            .then(function(result) {
              console.log("Notification sent");
              return null;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.log("Notification failed ", error);
              return null;
            });
      }
    });
```

I have tried many variations such as the get() function and on(), but all give me the same error, I was trying to check the docs on this but they only talked about database triggers so I'm not sure if normal retrieval can work or not.

EDIT:
I updated my code to reach the database node through the snapshot given in the onCreate event, and now it works, although I am facing another problem now, if I push a new doctor under the node "doctors" it doesn't call the function.. but if I hit "test" in the Google Cloud console and it calls the function I get "null" in my snapshot.val() and "undefined" in the newDoctorID above, whereas the snapshot.key gives "doctors", why is it not calling the onCreate function?

Comment: can you try changing this line functions  to admin like this  `const adminTokensRef = admin.database().ref("device_tokens/admin");`

Comment: @SathiAiswarya I have found another approach and it thankfully works, but now I'm facing a different issue, can you look at the edit above please?